# .Find macro not working if launched from worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use vba to write an "X" into the column with the current date.
If I run the code from the debug window, where I write the code it works as intented, but as soon as I try to run it by clicking on the rectangle I assigned it to, it says "Not found".

Thanks in advance for any help or ideas.

The code:

```
Sub Button()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim col As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet 2")

    With ws.Cells
        Set rng = .Find(what:=Format(Date))
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Not found"
            col = 1
        Else
            MsgBox "Found"
            col = rng.Column
        End If
    End With
    ws.Cells(10, col).Value = "X"
    MsgBox "Wrote to Field: " & row & "," & col

End Sub
```

Comment: Try including a format description in the *Format()* function that matches your data.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent thanks for the answer, do you mean like this `Format(Date, "dd.mm.yyyy")` ? I still get the same error.

Comment: Is Activeworkbook what you think it is?

Comment: @HarassedDad I think so, atleast it finds the right sheet in the next line and its the only open workbook. The behaviour doesn't change either if I set it by name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace *Format(Date)* with *CDate(Date)*

Comment: Okay, this kinda works. Now it the macro doesn't work if I run it in debug, but if I click on the rectangle it works. That's so weird

Comment: Okay I changed nothing, but today it works from the debug screen as well. Thanks